# Trying to fetch records older than 30 days in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to fetch the records in Oracle sql which is older than 30 days (from Mod_date) and I am using the below query and it is returning all the data and I want only 30 days old data. Will you please anyone help me to correct this query Sample :- Mod_date 03-NOV-12 12.00.00.000000000 AM  Query :-

```
select Mod_date 
from fil_cnfact 
where Mod_date <= sysdate -30 
order by Mod_date asc ;
```

Comment: Your query is correct, if you want all Mod_date that are older than 30 days. But a few things to consider 1. sysdate is date + time (trunc it if you really mean date); 2. Are you sure you really mean 30 days and not a month ago (remember that months are not necessarily 30 days)?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is asking for all records less than or equal to 30 days from today. Change your operator to `=` only to request records that are 30 days old.

```
select Mod_date 
from fil_cnfact 
where trunc(Mod_date) = trunc(sysdate)-30 
order by Mod_date asc ;
```

Comment: Hi Matt if I use '>'   then the query is working as expected . I mean like this below,                                                               select Mod_date 
from fil_cnfact 
where trunc(Mod_date) >= trunc(sysdate)-30 
order by Mod_date asc ;  thanks for your query ....